# How to pass a form and other variables to theme functions?

Tags: forms, theming

I wonder how can I pass a form and other variables (an array) to `hook_theme()`, I know that if you want to render a form in hook theme you have to use `'render element'` so now I can't use `'variables'` to pass my variable array. here is what I did to render the form:

```
function example_theme() {
  return array(
    'deductible_form' => array(
      'arguments'      => array('form' => NULL),
      'template'       => 'example',    
      'render element' => 'form',    
     ),
  );
}
```

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you rightly say you can't pass variables to a theme function that uses a `render element`, but then you don't need to.

One of the points of the render element is that the element already contains all of the properties/variables that it needs to perform the render, without having to get them from anywhere else.

A themed form is actually a good example for this: if you need to add extra variables in order to render that form, then they should be arguments to the form function itself. e.g.:

```
function deductible_form($form, &$form_state, $var1, $var2) {
  $form['#theme'] = 'deductible_form';
  $form['#var1'] = $var1;
  $form['#var2'] = $var2;

  // etc...

  return $form;
}
```

Then in your form's theme function you can easily access those vars:

```
function theme_deductible_form($vars) {
  $form = $vars['form'];

  $var1 = $form['#var1'];
  $var2 = $form['#var2'];

  // Render the form
}
```

All you need to do to get that form to render properly now is to call `drupal_get_form()` with your extra variables:

```
$form = drupal_get_form('deductible_form', $var1, $var2);
```

Comment: thanks you for this info, but i was talking about how to pass the variable to the template itself so i can access in template.tpl.php itself

Comment: It's exactly the same method...in your template file your vars will be in `$form['#var1']`, `$form['#var2']` etc